# Python API - Export Grease Pencil as SVG or as PDF

Tags: python, export, grease-pencil, svg

I know the new Grease pencil exports are written in C and just released in 2.93 but I was wondering if there is a python api to run these export commands or a workaround.

Comment: Have you enabled python tool tips? You can check for it that way usually.

Comment: Yeah that was one of the first things I tried. All I see that could be related is `bpy.ops.file.execute()` but nothing stands out as being the correct python call.

Answer (score 1):

Followup

svg
`bpy.ops.wm.gpencil_export_svg(filepath='/your/filepath/test.svg')`

pdf
`bpy.ops.wm.gpencil_export_pdf(filepath='/your/filepath/test.svg')`

I found this out by looking at this commit

https://developer.blender.org/rBa8a92cd15a5251377474fbfdcf9ff0298a8457a9